# Inno Setup: Modify icon and title of specific error message

Tags: inno-setup

I have a program that should only be installed on 64-bit architectures. So I added:

```
ArchitecturesAllowed = x64
```

In my Inno Setup file to prevent this.

The problem is that the message displayed is a bit too "violent". It displays "error" in title and a big red cross.

I've found that I can change content of this message (with `OnlyOnTheseArchitectures` message), but no way to modify icon and title without impacting other error message.

And I do not see what step can match...

Is there a way to make it like an information box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no generic way to modify any standard Inno Setup message box.

You generally have to re-implement the function on your own. What is not always possible.

---

For your specific case, you are lucky, as you can easily implement your own custom check for 64-bit system using the [`IsWin64` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64) from the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

And display your own custom message box using the [`MsgBox` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_msgbox).

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if not IsWin64 then
  begin
    MsgBox('This cannot be installed on 32-bit system.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image: This cannot be installed on 32-bit system]

Comment: Works as expected.